# This interaction has already been acknowledged

Tags: java, multithreading, discord-jda

I'm creating a discord bot that I use multi-threading to update an ArrayList every few minutes. The first 'update' works correctly with no error, though every update afterwards I get the error:

```
[JDA MainWS-ReadThread] ERROR RestAction - RestAction queue returned failure
java.lang.IllegalStateException: This interaction has already been acknowledgdge an interaction once!
```

I'm creating the threads in `Multithread.java` which says:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        // Create a new bot
        Thread startApp = new Thread(new App());
        
        // Start the thread
        startApp.start();

        // Create new thread for updating
        new App();
        Thread updateTeams  = new Thread(App.updateAll());
        updateTeams.start();

    }
```

The ArrayList that i'm updating (OCETeams) is in App.java and is public and static.

In `App.java`, I have the following methods that relate to this:

```
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            System.out.println("Starting.............");
            initialize();
        } catch (LoginException | ParseException | InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    // For the 'updating' thread    
    public static Runnable updateAll() {
        Timer timer = new Timer();
        timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    System.out.println("Updating all");
                    OCETeams = getOCETeams();
                    System.out.println("OCE teams updated");
                } catch (ParseException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            
        } , 0, 60000 * 20);

        return null;
    }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Interaction has already been acknowledged](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71702161/interaction-has-already-been-acknowledged)

Comment: The code you provided has nothing to do with the exception.

Comment: Doesn’t it? I’m not sure what causes this error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In essence you have already replied for example and you are trying to reply again which throws the error and there is not enough info from the code you provided.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).